# How ORDER BY works in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

assume there is a table with 100 million records in it with this schema:

```
+---------+---------+------+
| user_id | post_id | date |
+---------+---------+------+
```

We want to have latest 30 records which user with #1 is posted.

```
SELECT * FROM users_posts WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30
```

How MySQL search in table ? Does it search all rows ( full scan ) finding all matches THEN ordering them by date?

if Yes( Full Scan ), how can we edit this query to limit it to search latest records till finds 30 matches. ( to increase reading speed and have better performance )

thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can see what MySQL does by pre-pending the query with `explain` (whose results are well-documented).  To limit the results, use `limit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the best performance for this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_posts
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Then you want an index on `users_posts(user_id, date)`.  This will allow the SQL engine to only use the index to define the set of rows being used.  First, it will use `user_id` to satisfy the `where` clause.  Then it will use the `date` part for the `order by`.  It will still have to look up the records in the original data pages, in order to get all the columns needed for the `select`.

If you want to limit this to 30 rows, then add `limit 30`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_posts
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

With the above index, this will improve performance.  With no index, the engine will have to scan all the data, sort the data that matches the `where` clause, and then apply the `limit` -- in other words, it won't be much of an improvement in performance.

Comment: making user_id and date as compound index is better or index them separately?

Comment: @Pars . . . For this query, a composite index is the way to go.